# How to Passing Arguments to a shell modular programming

Tags: module, kernel-module

I try to built modular programming  Makefile for compiling a module named hello-1.c.
I researched create make file and built video but i couldn't success.

My code :

```
#include <linux/module.h>   
#include <linux/kernel.h>   

int init_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world \n");
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world \n");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you look up youtube modular programming , it tell you how to compile.  To learn more on how to compile modules which are not part of the official kernel  see file linux/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt.

Makefile for compiling a module named your-file-name--1.c:

```
 obj-m += your-file-name-1.o
```

all:

```
 make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

clean:

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```